# Postgres Array Issue

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table as below and want the output to be loaded the data into another table:

Input Table Data(Tempabc):

```
ID,COURSE,ENROLL_DT
'12345fgh-2bce-467f',array['BB','TT',''],array['01/07/2007 12:00:00 AM','15/09/2007 12:00:00 AM',''],
'1234rty-863d-4e4f',array['CRKT','HKY',''],array['01/01/2005 12:00:00 AM','01/07/2012 12:00:00 AM','']
```

Output Data:

```
ID,COURSE,ENROLL_DT
'12345fgh-2bce-467f',array['BB','TT'],array['01/07/2007','15/09/2007'],
'1234rty-863d-4e4f',array['CRKT','HKY'],array['01/01/2005','01/07/2012']
```

Can you guys please help. I have used the below query however unable to extract date from the third column. The third column is a varchar column while importing from a file but I want to load it to target table where it is a Date datatype Array column:

```
SELECT ID,
ARRAY_REMOVE(COURSE,'') AS COURSE,ARRAY_REMOVE(ENROLL_DT,'') AS ENROLL_DT
FROM TEMPABC;
```

However, I am still unable to extract the date from the ENROLL_DT column. Is there a way to extract the Date. Can someone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the blank elements of the arrays and change their data type, you could `array_remove`, `unnest`, cast the values and finally group them again with `array_agg`, e.g.

```
WITH tempabc (id,course,enroll_dt) AS ( 
VALUES
  ('12345fgh-2bce-467f',array['BB','TT',''],array['01/07/2007 12:00:00 AM','15/09/2007 12:00:00 AM','']),
  ('1234rty-863d-4e4f',array['CRKT','HKY',''],array['01/01/2005 12:00:00 AM','01/07/2012 12:00:00 AM',''])
)
SELECT id, array_agg(course) AS course, array_agg(enroll_dt) AS enroll_dt FROM (
  SELECT id,
    unnest(array_remove(course,'')) AS course,
    unnest(array_remove(enroll_dt,''))::date AS enroll_dt
  FROM tempabc) q
GROUP BY id;

         id         |   course   |        enroll_dt        
--------------------+------------+-------------------------
 12345fgh-2bce-467f | {BB,TT}    | {2007-07-01,2007-09-15}
 1234rty-863d-4e4f  | {CRKT,HKY} | {2005-01-01,2012-07-01}
```

If you're aiming to create a record for each array value, just `array_remove` and `unnest`, e.g.

```
WITH tempabc (id,course,enroll_dt) AS ( 
VALUES
  ('12345fgh-2bce-467f',array['BB','TT',''],array['01/07/2007 12:00:00 AM','15/09/2007 12:00:00 AM','']),
  ('1234rty-863d-4e4f',array['CRKT','HKY',''],array['01/01/2005 12:00:00 AM','01/07/2012 12:00:00 AM',''])
)
SELECT id,
  unnest(array_remove(course,'')) AS course,
  unnest(array_remove(enroll_dt,''))::date AS enroll_dt
FROM tempabc;

         id         | course | enroll_dt  
--------------------+--------+------------
 12345fgh-2bce-467f | BB     | 2007-07-01
 12345fgh-2bce-467f | TT     | 2007-09-15
 1234rty-863d-4e4f  | CRKT   | 2005-01-01
 1234rty-863d-4e4f  | HKY    | 2012-07-01
```

Further reading:

- [`PostgreSQL Array Functions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html)
- [`PostgreSQL type cast :: operator`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/)